# How to fill third column in mySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns: a, b in mySQL table.

I want to add third column values (c) and fill it automatically by such way:

- if a = b -> c=1
- if a<>b -> c=0

What type of Query should I use?

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be added to the table? You could just calculate it when you select from the table if you need it

Comment: @ReeseDeWind Yes,  I know how to make it in a php, but I was needed it to be made via SQL itself. Anyway,  thank you for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generated column:

```
alter table t add c int generated always as (a = b);
```

This uses the fact that a boolean is treated as an integer in an integer context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: WOW! PERFECT! It even add automatically c value for new row with no need additional queries. This is better than I was really expected. Let God bless you! // I mark your answer in 9 minutes.